# Why is using atomic variable access is more efficient than accessing these variable through synchronised code?

Tags: java, synchronization, shared-memory, atomic, synchronized

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the concept of atomic access. I saw the statement below from Java Tutorial Oracle. My questions are:

1. why is using atomic variable access is more efficient than accessing these variable through synchronised code?
2. Why does using atomic variable access require more care by the programmer to avoid memory consistency errors.

I'm having a tough time get my head around it.

> Using simple atomic variable access is more efficient than accessing
>   these variables through synchronized code, but requires more care by
>   the programmer to avoid memory consistency errors. Whether the extra
>   effort is worthwhile depends on the size and complexity of the
>   application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to (1):** 
For read access, it does not matter whether it is atomic or non-atomic, synchronized or non-synchronized. 
For write access, atomic variable does not require lock to write because all update to variable happens atomic (either happened or not happened completely) For eg: suppose you want to do i++ in a multi threaded application and multiple threads can call this, you need to synchnorzied i++ call (as it is set to 3 registry levels call and you know it can be context switch at any point of registry level calls even in between) to avoid dirty reads and inconsistent write.
Whereas Atomic variable has just 1 registry level calls (thanks to additional register being added and our languages harnessing it).
Due to synchronized overhead (acquiring monitor locks and releasing thereafter), atomic variable access is more efficient than accessing these variable through synchronised code

**Answer to (2):**
All Objects in java require more care by the programmer to avoid memory consistency errors, doesnt matter whether it is Atomic or not.
While the siblings of Atomic variable can be primitive and not object, it doesnt falls into object category and hence not required to take care of memory consistency error
The reason why every object requires to avoid memory consistency errors in multithreaded application is because each thread stack caches the copy of object locally on thread stack (Runtime optimization) might result into not in sync with actual copy of heap if it gets modified by another thread (even in the same code but different thread stack). One solution to avoid is to use ***volatile*** for that object which can be changed by another thread frequently. Also the local copy tries to in sync with heap copy very fast but problem occurs if your thread access it more faster than sync happens.

Hope this helps you in understanding the atomic and memory access concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a variable as volatile means that modifying its value immediately affects the actual memory storage for the variable. The compiler cannot optimize away any references made to the variable. This guarantees that when one thread modifies the variable, all other threads see the new value immediately. (This is not necessarily true of non-volatile variables.)

Declaring an atomic variable guarantees that operations made on the variable occur in an atomic fashion, i.e., that all of the substeps of the operation are completed within the thread they are executed and are not interrupted by other threads. For example, an increment-and-test operation requires the variable to be incremented and then compared to another value; an atomic operation guarantees that both of these steps will be completed as if they were a single indivisible/uninterruptible operation.

Synchronizing all accesses to a variable allows only a single thread at a time to access the variable, and forces all other threads to wait for that accessing thread to release its access to the variable.

Synchronized access is similar to atomic access, but the atomic operations are generally implemented at a lower level of programming. Also, it is entirely possible to synchronize only some accesses to a variable and allow other accesses to be unsynchronized (e.g., synchronize all writes to a variable but none of the reads from it).

Atomicity, synchronization, and volatility are independent attributes, but are typically used in combination to enforce proper thread cooperation for accessing variables.